# Counting polygons overlapping point shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I've been through the similar questions and can't see a suitable answer.

I have a shapefile with 1000's of polygons that cover the country. What I want to do it create a regular spaced grid of points across the country (every 10x10km for example). Then for each point count how of the polygons in the other shapefile overlap that point. Essentially the output point dataset will indicate hot and low spots across the country.

I'm using QGIS 3.20. I need to understand the high and low extents.

Comment: Are you able to provide links to the similar questions that you found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make sure you have some column with values in it in your polygon layer, for example field calculate a `@row_number` column
2. **Join attributes by location (summary)**, with count as *Summaries to calculate*

[image]